Spring OAuthClient won't call token endpoint when receiving AuthCode
My Auth Server sends an auth code on valid credentials, but then my OAuthClient, instead of calling the token endpoint throws an error, and the Failure Handler gets triggered.
Auth Server's last logs are
2024-08-14T19:39:09.960+01:00 TRACE 81045 --- [nio-6060-exec-9] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=DocDbUserAuthentication [Principal=DocDbUser(userId=6679795af97993228321a131, username=userName.00@gmail.com, password=null, authorities=[ROLE_USER, AUTH_POST, AUTH_GET, AUTH_PUT, AUTH_PATCH, AUTH_DELETE], isAccountNonExpired=true, isAccountNonLocked=true, isCredentialsNonExpired=true, isEnabled=true), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, AUTH_POST, AUTH_GET, AUTH_PUT, AUTH_PATCH, AUTH_DELETE]]] from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2024-08-14T19:39:09.960+01:00 TRACE 81045 --- [nio-6060-exec-9] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider (1/17)

2024-08-14T19:39:10.128+01:00 DEBUG 81045 --- [nio-6060-exec-9] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:7080/bff/login/oauth2/code/in-house-auth-server?code=POe_muwSaQGWDeJKz9nhZq7JmjlRIbcwXUglD8N0mxefHljAC1XMsKmcSkJqFVhAeBrvEIVCn9euW5EmcM9QK9tP3R26PxQeHrKSACn8kNoomVTHzR69sNWKhMPqMTlG&state=0SO3T8pVc_XE9BKrGkadjpPYZtoko5CcRaYBWHuOwV0%3D

I'm then expecting a call to it's token endpoint from the OAuth client so it can generate tokens to send to it.
But the OAuth Client just does this:
Failure handler gets triggered, and this gets done:
ON FAILURE REDIRECT URI: http://localhost:7080/angular-ui/login-error
URI with Query Parameters: http://localhost:7080/angular-ui/login-error?error=%5Bauthorization_request_not_found%5D%20
RUNNING SERVER REDIRECT STRATEGY: 302 FOUND

My security chain
 // oauth2.0 client login
    http.oauth2Login { oauth2 ->
        oauth2.authorizationRequestResolver(oauthAuthorizationRequestResolver)
        oauth2.authorizationRequestRepository(redisAuthorizationRequestRepository)
        oauth2.authorizationRedirectStrategy(preAuthorizationCodeRedirectStrategy)
        oauth2.authenticationSuccessHandler(delegatingAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
        oauth2.authenticationFailureHandler(oauth2ServerAuthenticationFailureHandler)


        oauth2.clientRegistrationRepository(reactiveClientRegistrationRepository)
        oauth2.authorizedClientRepository(reactiveAuthorizedClientRepository)
        oauth2.authorizedClientService(reactiveAuthorizedClientService)
    }

The failure handler
@Component
internal class OAuth2ServerAuthenticationFailureHandler(
    oauth2RedirectionProperties: OAuth2RedirectionProperties,
    private val loginProperties: LoginProperties
) : ServerAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    // construct default re-direct uri
    private val defaultRedirectUri: URI = oauth2RedirectionProperties.getLoginErrorRedirectUri()
        ?: URI.create("/")

    // construct the default redirect strategy
    private val redirectStrategy: OAuth2ServerRedirectStrategy = OAuth2ServerRedirectStrategy(
        oauth2RedirectionProperties.postAuthorizationCode
    )

    // override onSuccess function
    override fun onAuthenticationFailure(
        webFilterExchange: WebFilterExchange,
        exception: AuthenticationException?
    ): Mono<Void>? {
        return webFilterExchange.exchange?.session?.flatMap { session ->

            // retrieve the post-login failure URI from session or use a default URI
            val uriString = session.getAttributeOrDefault(
                loginProperties.POST_AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE_URI_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE,
                defaultRedirectUri.toString()
            )

            println("ON FAILURE REDIRECT URI: $uriString")

            // decode the exception message
            val decodedMessageMono = Mono.fromCallable {
                URLDecoder.decode(exception?.message ?: "unknown error", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
            }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())


            // add query param to uri
            decodedMessageMono.flatMap { decodedMessage ->
                val encodedMessage = UriUtils.encodePath(
                    decodedMessage, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()
                )

                // build the URI with the properly encoded query parameter
                val uriWithQueryParam = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(URI.create(uriString))
                    .queryParam(
                        loginProperties.POST_AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE_CAUSE_ATTRIBUTE,
                        encodedMessage
                    ).build(true)
                    .toUri()

                println("URI with Query Parameters: $uriWithQueryParam")

                // Apply the redirect and return Mono<Void>
                redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(
                    webFilterExchange.exchange,
                    uriWithQueryParam
                )
            }
        }
    }

}

I am also attempting to call the AuthRequest object from Redis, via this repository, which calls the Redis Template, which calls the Redis Serialiser.
@Repository
internal class RedisAuthorizationRequestRepository(
    private val redisTemplate: ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, Any>,
    springSessionProperties: SpringSessionProperties,
    private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper
) : ServerAuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> {

    private val redisKeyPrefix = springSessionProperties.redis?.oauth2RequestNamespace

    override fun saveAuthorizationRequest(
        authorizationRequest: OAuth2AuthorizationRequest?,
        exchange: ServerWebExchange
    ): Mono<Void> {
        return constructRedisKey(exchange).flatMap { redisKey ->
            println("SAVING AUTHORIZATION REQUEST")
            println("Redis Key: $redisKey")

            if (authorizationRequest != null) {
                val hashOperations = redisTemplate.opsForHash<String, Any>()
                val fieldsMap = objectMapper.convertValue(
                    authorizationRequest,
                    object : TypeReference<Map<String, Any>>() {}
                )

                println("Authorization Request: $authorizationRequest")
                println("Fields Map: $fieldsMap")

                hashOperations.putAll(redisKey, fieldsMap).doOnSuccess {
                    println("Successfully saved authorization request to Redis")
                }.doOnError { e ->
                    println("Error saving authorization request to Redis: ${e.message}")
                }.then()
            } else {
                println("Authorization request is null, deleting Redis key: $redisKey")
                redisTemplate.opsForHash<String, Any>().delete(redisKey)
                    .doOnSuccess {
                        println("Successfully deleted authorization request from Redis")
                    }.doOnError { e ->
                        println("Error deleting authorization request from Redis: ${e.message}")
                    }.then()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun loadAuthorizationRequest(exchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest?> {
        return constructRedisKey(exchange).flatMap { redisKey ->
            println("LOADING AUTHORIZATION REQUEST")
            println("Redis Key: $redisKey")

            redisTemplate.opsForHash<String, Any>().entries(redisKey)
                .doOnNext { entries ->
                    println("Redis Entries: $entries")
                }
                .collectMap({ it.key as String }, { it.value })
                .doOnSuccess { map ->
                    println("Loaded Map from Redis: $map")
                }
                .mapNotNull { map ->
                    if (map.isEmpty()) {
                        println("Loaded map is empty, returning null")
                        null
                    } else {
                        try {
                            val authorizationRequest = objectMapper.convertValue(map, OAuth2AuthorizationRequest::class.java)
                            println("Deserialized OAuth2AuthorizationRequest: $authorizationRequest")
                            authorizationRequest
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            println("Error deserializing OAuth2AuthorizationRequest: ${e.message}")
                            null
                        }
                    }
                }
                .doOnError { e ->
                    println("Error loading authorization request: ${e.message}")
                }
        }
    }

    override fun removeAuthorizationRequest(exchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest?> {
        println("REMOVING AUTHORIZATION REQUEST")
        return constructRedisKey(exchange).flatMap { redisKey ->
            println("Attempting to remove Authorization Request with key: $redisKey")
            redisTemplate.opsForHash<String, Any>().entries(redisKey)
                .doOnNext { entries ->
                    println("Current Redis Entries: $entries")
                }
                .collectMap({ it.key as String }, { it.value })
                .doOnNext { map ->
                    println("Removing Authorization Request with data: $map")
                }
                .flatMap { map ->
                    redisTemplate.opsForHash<String, Any>().delete(redisKey)
                        .then(Mono.fromCallable {
                            try {
                                val authorizationRequest = objectMapper.convertValue(map, OAuth2AuthorizationRequest::class.java)
                                println("Successfully removed Authorization Request from Redis. Data: $authorizationRequest")
                                authorizationRequest
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                println("Error deserializing Authorization Request after removal: ${e.message}")
                                null
                            }
                        })
                }
                .onErrorResume { e ->
                    println("Error occurred while removing Authorization Request: ${e.message}")
                    Mono.empty()
                }
        }
    }

    // Helper method to construct the Redis key using a unique identifier from the exchange
    private fun constructRedisKey(exchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<String> {
        return exchange.session
            .map { it.id }
            .map { "$redisKeyPrefix:$it" }
    }
}

But I don't understand where I'm going wrong. Is it that the AuthReques details arent being retrived and so the OauthFailure handler is always triggering?
GitHub Repo
The full repo with code can be found here:
Spring BFF GitHub Repo - trying to back repos into Redis
Redis
Both the request and session are appearing in Redis, I can see them here, with the same key, but in slightly different namespaces:


I'd be grateful if anyone can help
UPDATE:
For some reason in the OauthFlow it tries to remove the OAuthRequest from Redis, but then hits a de-serialisaton error. I'd have thought it would have tried to call the load OAuthRequest function, rather than remove function in the RedisAuthorizationRequestRepository class
REMOVING AUTHORIZATION REQUEST
Attempting to remove Authorization Request with key: spring:session:bff:oauth2:authorization-request:BFF-64b66250-f21d-4bc2-9983-a7c472e9d0ef
Current Redis Entries: authorizationUri=http://localhost:7080/auth/oauth2/authorize
Current Redis Entries: responseType={value=code}
Current Redis Entries: scopes=[openid]
Current Redis Entries: attributes={registration_id=in-house-auth-server, nonce=q9nBQZkEnC0DdT6mXPxyxi3953UGDOG-gGavQfu0vcaFNQUy811KU2xWuu-UovBdg23l9gYYE41ZmO2Ck8iQm8HCP8i6ruyffyupjMo1SUFgtalj-advJmjYnlsdJHEB, code_verifier=EPxjw9kgEaZlM_akS2b3HGOd54RNiXSNvdP8Bs-C3WIUA7_Dn0n4rlxv5YBlQCaNylMTiNzI2NjfcowC_oxp8ChEHa42uvlsJhwTJ9hK19QninngKw8SrSMzdMXsXNr5}
Current Redis Entries: grantType={value=authorization_code}
Current Redis Entries: additionalParameters={nonce=m6bE5gMLDglQnYpfYEZ7ybzCpa2UMcxsvwIuWWYkqVo, code_challenge=xN_S6BKCKb8oTHCRPiqrQTLwEwkfjPxq3HLJpFN2YXE, code_challenge_method=S256}
Current Redis Entries: state=P_jqQY3rhisa-o15_6lYKzoVmEwmwUDIQccYDq8WWGY=
Current Redis Entries: authorizationRequestUri=http://localhost:7080/auth/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=bff_client&scope=openid&state=P_jqQY3rhisa-o15_6lYKzoVmEwmwUDIQccYDq8WWGY%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:7080/bff/login/oauth2/code/in-house-auth-server&nonce=m6bE5gMLDglQnYpfYEZ7ybzCpa2UMcxsvwIuWWYkqVo&code_challenge=xN_S6BKCKb8oTHCRPiqrQTLwEwkfjPxq3HLJpFN2YXE&code_challenge_method=S256
Current Redis Entries: redirectUri=http://localhost:7080/bff/login/oauth2/code/in-house-auth-server
Current Redis Entries: clientId=bff_client
Removing Authorization Request with data: {redirectUri=http://localhost:7080/bff/login/oauth2/code/in-house-auth-server, authorizationUri=http://localhost:7080/auth/oauth2/authorize, responseType={value=code}, clientId=bff_client, authorizationRequestUri=http://localhost:7080/auth/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=bff_client&scope=openid&state=P_jqQY3rhisa-o15_6lYKzoVmEwmwUDIQccYDq8WWGY%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:7080/bff/login/oauth2/code/in-house-auth-server&nonce=m6bE5gMLDglQnYpfYEZ7ybzCpa2UMcxsvwIuWWYkqVo&code_challenge=xN_S6BKCKb8oTHCRPiqrQTLwEwkfjPxq3HLJpFN2YXE&code_challenge_method=S256, attributes={registration_id=in-house-auth-server, nonce=q9nBQZkEnC0DdT6mXPxyxi3953UGDOG-gGavQfu0vcaFNQUy811KU2xWuu-UovBdg23l9gYYE41ZmO2Ck8iQm8HCP8i6ruyffyupjMo1SUFgtalj-advJmjYnlsdJHEB, code_verifier=EPxjw9kgEaZlM_akS2b3HGOd54RNiXSNvdP8Bs-C3WIUA7_Dn0n4rlxv5YBlQCaNylMTiNzI2NjfcowC_oxp8ChEHa42uvlsJhwTJ9hK19QninngKw8SrSMzdMXsXNr5}, additionalParameters={nonce=m6bE5gMLDglQnYpfYEZ7ybzCpa2UMcxsvwIuWWYkqVo, code_challenge=xN_S6BKCKb8oTHCRPiqrQTLwEwkfjPxq3HLJpFN2YXE, code_challenge_method=S256}, scopes=[openid], state=P_jqQY3rhisa-o15_6lYKzoVmEwmwUDIQccYDq8WWGY=, grantType={value=authorization_code}}
Error deserializing Authorization Request after removal: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationResponseType` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN] (through reference chain: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationRequest["responseType"])

So, I'm still stuck...

@jzheaux - not sure if you are familiar with this error?
